# Passing variables from method to draw a line - Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to call a method from a button click and from that method I want to pass variables to the class DrawPanel which extends Jpanel to draw a line. I have 4 classes, MainFem, DrawPanel, DrawLine and Callmethod1.

The problem is that the new values don't get added in the LinkedList.

**Main class: MainFem**

```
package paintpack;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class MainFem extends JFrame {

JPanel buttonsPanel = null;
JButton dcomp = null;
DrawPanel drawPanel = null;

  public MainFem(){

  add(getDrawPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);

  add(getButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  getButtonPanel().add(getDcomp());
  }

  private JPanel getButtonPanel() {
  if(buttonsPanel == null){
      buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
       buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      buttonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
  }

  return buttonsPanel;
  }



  private DrawPanel getDrawPanel(){
  if(drawPanel == null){
      drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
      drawPanel.setVisible(true);
  }

  return drawPanel;
  }



  private JButton getDcomp() {
  if(dcomp == null){
      dcomp = new JButton("Click");
      dcomp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              Callmethod1 call1 = new Callmethod1();
              call1.passmethod1();
              getDrawPanel().repaint();
          }
      });
  }
  return dcomp;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
MainFem wnd = new MainFem();


wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
wnd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
Container c = wnd.getContentPane();
c.setBackground(Color.red); 
wnd.pack();
wnd.setVisible(true);



}

}
```

**DrawPanel class**

```
package paintpack;


import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class DrawPanel extends JPanel{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private DrawLines dlines; 

public DrawPanel() {
    dlines = new DrawLines();
}

public void method1(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    dlines.addLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    repaint();
    //System.out.println("bingo");
}



// beging PAINTING
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    dlines.draw(g);

}

}
```

**DrawLines**

```
package paintpack;


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class DrawLines{

public DrawLines() {

}

private static class Line {
    final int x1;
    final int y1;
    final int x2;
    final int y2;

    public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;

    }

}

private final LinkedList<Line> lines = new LinkedList<Line>();

public void addLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    lines.add(new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2));
}

public void clearLines() {
    lines.clear();
}

public void draw(Graphics g){
    for (Line line : lines) {
        g.drawLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);
    }
}
```

}

**Callmethod1**

```
package paintpack;


public class Callmethod1 {
private DrawPanel pass1;

public Callmethod1() {
pass1 = new DrawPanel();
}

public void passmethod1(){
pass1.method1(300, 300, 200, 200);
pass1.repaint();
}

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are having?

Comment: There is no line plotted anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you allocate a new instance of `DrawPanel` in the constructor of `Callmethod1`. So you are drawing lines on another instance of `DrawPanel` which is invisible. To fix it just pass an instance of existing `DrawPanel`, ei:

```
public Callmethod1(DrawPanel drawPanel) {
    this.pass1 = drawPanel;
}
```

And in the action listener:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Callmethod1 call1 = new Callmethod1(drawPanel);
    call1.passmethod1();
}
```

As a side note, you can utilize existing [Line2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html) class to draw lines.

Comment: Also, what if I want from the button click to call function1 first and from function1 call Callmethod1 ?

Comment: @Steve Not sure what is the problem with `function1`, where is it defined? Look into [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). Your `Callmethod1` can be an action that you can execute from button, toolbar, menu etc.

Comment: Ok I found it. it's defined inside DrawPanel. I just have to pass the instance of the existin DrawPanel:

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 drawPanel.another(drawPanel);
 }

public void another(DrawPanel drawPanel){
   Callmethod1 call1 = new Callmethod1(drawPanel);
     call1.passmethod1();
     drawPanel.repaint();
 }